# Signaling threads to stop

Tags: c#

have such code.

Start threads:

```
Thread[] thr;
static object locker = new object();
bool liking = true;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = true;
    string post = create_note();

    decimal value = Program.Data.numericUpDown1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = (int)(value);
    thr = new Thread[j];
    for (; i < j; i++)
    {
        thr[i] = new Thread(() => invite(post)); 
        thr[i].IsBackground = true;
        thr[i].Start();
    }

}
public void invite(string post)
{
    while (liking)
    {
        if (//some comdition)
            exit all threads, and start string post = create_note(); again
    }
}
```

If some condition in `invite(string post)` comes true I need to stop all threads, and go to `string post = create_note();` again, get string post and start threads again.

How to do it?

Comment: Set `liking` to `false`. As your threads seem to regularly check this variable, the should exit.

Comment: Unless you have a special need to use `Threads`, I suggest you use `Tasks` and `CancellationToken` to accomplish this.

Comment: What exactly did you do to determine the optimum value of the "value" variable?  How many Internet connections do you have?  Web sites often intentionally permit only one active connection per IP address.  So why is it not 1?  Which of course trivially solves the problem.

Comment: @Madushan Never worked with Tasks, can you show me on my code how to re-write it?

Comment: Note, that you'd need to use `VolatileRead` or set `liking` to be `volatile` in order for this to work. Otherwise it'll just be optimized to `if(liking) while(true) {.....}`.

Comment: @Alxandr Is it really?

Comment: Why can't you just loop through the `Thread[]` and call `Thread.Abort()`?

Comment: @CédricBignon yes. This is one of the harder bugs to catch though, cause the compiler only does this when you optimize (ie. not on debug-builds). You have to know about this on your own.

Comment: @Alxandr I never had this problem before. Even in Release mode without debugger. And I've tested with a small program, it works without `volatile`.

Comment: Hmm. It might depend on optimizations used... I just watched a video from a "concurrency-expert" in C#. He stated that because the compiler makes no guarantees about multi-threaded code, that optimization is entirely valid. Also, I'm not sure if the optimization is done from C# -> IL, or by the jitter. But I do believe I managed to reproduce the behavior. It's just been a rule of thumb for me in these kinds of loops, though times may have changed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lock and create a class that manage your threads like that :

```
public class SyncClass
{
    public Thread[] thr;
    private int NumberOfWorkingThreads { get; set; }
    private object Sync = new object();

    public int ThreadNumber { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler TasksFinished;

    public SyncClass(int threadNumber)
    {
        thr = new Thread[threadNumber];
        ThreadNumber = threadNumber;
        NumberOfWorkingThreads = ThreadNumber;
        //LunchThreads(threadNumber);
    }

    protected void OnTasksFinished()
    {
        if (TasksFinished == null)
            return;
        lock (Sync)
        {
            NumberOfWorkingThreads--;
            if (NumberOfWorkingThreads == 0)
                TasksFinished(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void LunchThreads()
    {
        string post = create_note();
        for (int i = 0; i < ThreadNumber; i++)
        {
            thr[i] = new Thread(() => invite(post));
            thr[i].IsBackground = true;                
            thr[i].Start();
        }
    }

    private void invite(string post)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        OnTasksFinished();
    }


}
```

Use the event to notify the end of all threads then the class will be used like that:

```
    private void Operation()
    {
        var sync = new SyncClass(10);
        sync.TasksFinished += sync_TasksFinished;
        sync.LunchThreads();
    }



     void sync_TasksFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Operation();
    }
```

Comment: I have some problems( What method have I add to button2_Click? Operation()? I add your class SyncClass and receive exception `Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'OD_like_combine.Form1' via nested type 'OD_like_combine.Form1.SyncClass' C:\work\Projects\OD like combine\OD like combine\Form1.cs`

Comment: From the exception I think you misused the class a little (You are trying to access a member of your form from withing the SyncClass and that member is not static so you can't), add the class SyncClass, and the create the function Operation to your form and every think should work fine. also pass what you need in your calculation as a parameter to the constructor and like that you shouldn't need any external members. I hope I am clear.

Comment: I received your project

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manual thread management, use [`Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) with [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.cancellationtoken.aspx):

```
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var options = new ParallelOptions 
        { 
            CancellationToken = cts.Token,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount
        };
        var result = Parallel.For(0, j, options, i =>
        {
            invite(post);
            options.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        });
```

When you want to cancel parallel calculations, just call `cts.Cancel()` from external code.

Comment: I need start a big number of threads, for example 200, is Parallel supports it?

Comment: @Kenji: no, you don't need this, really. It is very inefficient to start a number of threads, that exceeds a number of CPU cores. Of course, technically, you may set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 200, but this won't help you.

Comment: @Dennis6 I need this really)

Comment: @Kenji: you can't jump over your head. You can't force the computer to run more parallel calculations, than the number of CPU cores. You can start more and more threads, but this won't be "faster". Huge number of threads it's just a way to consume more memory and put CPU(s) to more often context switching.

Comment: @Kenji Why do you need 200 threads at the same time? It will certainly be less efficient than 10 threads doing 20 times the same job.